# How can I see the entire error message when a test email fails and gives an error, in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

How can I see the whole error message in Outlook 2007?  I can't slide it over; I can't copy and paste it; I just can't see the whole message.  What simply thing am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. This is the common Exchange Server's "Client does not have permissions to send as this sender" error. Looks like you're trying to send the message from the mailbox/contact you don't have persmissions to send from (Send As).